# inserting string/var into a file before process

Tags: php

I'm processing a html email template, everything works fine. I just need to do one more thing, add the username into the email `$en['user'];` is this possible when loading html content from a file? Or, do I have to inline the html email tpl code into the process mail file?

```
...
$body = file_get_contents('emails/welcome.tpl');
mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
```

**EDIT: would this be the solution?** in reference to @Dagon comment below?

```
$tpl_body = file_get_contents('emails/welcome.tpl');
$body = str_replace("%user%",$en['user'],$tpl_body);

mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: str_replace, preg_replace ...

Comment: @Dagon I made a change to my code above, would it work the way that I posted?

Answer (score 0):

using @Dagon suggestion for `str_replace` my solution is below....

```
$tpl_body = file_get_contents('emails/welcome.tpl');
$body = str_replace("%user%",$en['user'],$tpl_body);

mail($en['email'], $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ob_start();
include 'foo.tpl';
$body = ob_get_clean();
```